# Organising Sliding Divs using z-index?

Tags: jquery, css, html, z-index, slidetoggle

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/V2JJ4/

Here I have hidden divs that slide toggle open and closed.

All the links are available in each div so the user can toggle any div whichever div is open at the time. However, they are all sitting on different layers and for example if the user has toggled open the 'imagesDiv' and then clicks on one of the other links one can not see the other div open.

How do I organise these Divs so which ever div is toggled it will slide open on top of the Div open? Do I use z-index?

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hidden').hide()
});

$('.soundDiv-link').click(function() {
    $('#soundDiv').slideToggle("slow")
});

$('.videoDiv-link').click(function() {
    $('#videoDiv').animate({width: 'toggle'}, "slow")
});

$('.imagesDiv-link').click(function() {
    $('#imagesDiv').animate({width: 'toggle'}, "slow")
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="soundDiv-link" href="#" >sound-link</a>
<a class="videoDiv-link" href="#" >video-link</a>
<a class="imagesDiv-link" href="#" >images-link</a>

<div class="hidden" id="soundDiv">
    <a class="soundDiv-link" href="#" >sound-link</a>
    <a class="videoDiv-link" href="#" >video-link</a>
    <a class="imagesDiv-link" href="#" >images-link</a>
</div>

<div id="videoDiv">
    <a class="soundDiv-link" href="#" >sound-link</a>
    <a class="videoDiv-link" href="#" >video-link</a>
    <a class="imagesDiv-link" href="#" >images-link</a>
</div>

<div id="imagesDiv">
    <a class="soundDiv-link" href="#" >sound-link</a>
    <a class="videoDiv-link" href="#" >video-link</a>
    <a class="imagesDiv-link" href="#" >images-link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide the html markup? i see it now

Comment: simple solution here http://jsfiddle.net/V2JJ4/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can fix by changing the code to always make the last selected div on top:

```
var curZTop = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hidden').hide()
});

$('.soundDiv-link').click(function () {
$('#soundDiv').css("z-index", curZTop++);    $('#soundDiv').slideToggle("slow");

});

$('.videoDiv-link').click(function () {
    $('#videoDiv').css("z-index", curZTop++);    
    $('#videoDiv').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, "slow")
});

$('.imagesDiv-link').click(function () {
    $('#imagesDiv').css("z-index", curZTop++);
    $('#imagesDiv').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, "slow")
});
```

**EDIT**: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eJ3tf/

Answer (score 0):

I am using this jquery for same purpose.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hidden').hide()
});

$('.soundDiv-link').click(function() {
    $('#videoDiv, #imagesDiv').css('z-index', 1);
    $('#soundDiv').css('z-index', 2).slideToggle("slow")
});

$('.videoDiv-link').click(function() {
  $('#soundDiv, #imagesDiv').css('z-index', 1);
  $('#videoDiv').css('z-index', 2).animate({width: 'toggle'}, "slow")
});

$('.imagesDiv-link').click(function() {
  $('#videoDiv, #soundDiv').css('z-index', 1);
  $('#imagesDiv').css('z-index', 2).animate({width: 'toggle'}, "slow")
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a class="soundDiv-link" href="#" >sound-link</a>
<a class="videoDiv-link" href="#" >video-link</a>
<a class="imagesDiv-link" href="#" >images-link</a>

<div class="hidden" id="soundDiv">
<a class="soundDiv-link" href="#" >sound-link</a>
<a class="videoDiv-link" href="#" >video-link</a>
<a class="imagesDiv-link" href="#" >images-link</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
#soundDiv {
    background-color: #000;
}
#videoDiv {
    background-color: #666;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
#imagesDiv {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
.soundDiv-link, .videoDiv-link, .imagesDiv-link {
    position:absolute;
}
.soundDiv-link {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

.videoDiv-link {
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
}

.imagesDiv-link  {
    top: 100px;
    left: 200px;
}
```

Examlple http://jsfiddle.net/V2JJ4/4/